# displayBooks function c++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I need to display the information for a book. All data needs to be displayed through the displayBooks() function in driver.cpp. It must output the Title, the author, the number of pages in each book, and the price of each book. Driver.h and driver.cpp were provided for me, and the guidelines for Author class and Book class were also given. Here below is my code:

DRIVER.CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "driver.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // create a vector for storing the account objects
    vector<Book> myBooks;

    // create three Author objects
    Author p1("J.K.Rowling", "Edinburgh, Scotland");
    Author p2("Suzanne Collins", "Connecticut, USA");
    Author p3("J.R.R. Tolkien", "Bournmouth, England");

    // Create three Book objects
    Book b1(p1, "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 256, 24.95);
    Book b2(p2, "Mockingjay", 400, 12.99);
    Book b3(p3, "The Hobbit", 322, 14.29);

    // add the books to the vector
    myBooks.push_back(b1);
    myBooks.push_back(b2);
    myBooks.push_back(b3);

    // call the displayBooks function to display the books
    displayBooks(myBooks);
    cout << "\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void displayBooks(const vector<Book>& books)
{

    // students need to write the code for this function
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
    {
        //THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO WRITE
    }
}
```

DRIVER.H

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

// The displayBooks function
// Purpose: Display all of the data about a book
// Parameters: A vector of Book objects
// Returns: none
void displayBooks(const vector<Book>&);
```

BOOK.CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Author.h"

Book::Book()
{
    title = "";
    pageNumber = 0;
    price = 0;
}


Book::Book(Author a, string t, int pn, double p)
{
    author = a;
    title = t;
    pageNumber = pn;
    price = p;
}

string Book::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

int Book::getPageNumber()
{
    return pageNumber;
}

double Book::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
```

BOOK.H

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Author.h"
using namespace std;

class Book
{
private:
    Author author;
    string title;
    int pageNumber;
    double price;
public:

    // The default constructor for the Book class
    // Purpose: none
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    Book();

    // The constructor for the Book class
    // Purpose: Take in parameters to initialize class
    // Parameters: Author object, title string, page number int, price double
    // Returns: none
    Book(Author, string, int, double);

    // The get title function
    // Purpose: get titleof a book
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    string getTitle();

    // The get page number function
    // Purpose: Get page number of a book
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    int getPageNumber();

    // The get price function
    // Purpose: Get the price of a book
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    double getPrice();



};
```

AUTHOR.CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Author.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

Author::Author()
{
    name = "";
    address = "";
}


Author::Author(string n, string a)
{
    name = n;
    address = a;
}

string Author::getAddress()
{
    return address;
}

string Author::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

AUTHOR.H

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Author
{
private: 
    string address,
        name;
public:

    // The default constructor for the Autho class
    // Purpose: Construct the author class
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    Author();

    // The constructor for the Author class
    // Purpose: Take in parameters to initialize class
    // Parameters: string address, string name
    // Returns: none
    Author(string, string);

    // The get address function
    // Purpose: get the address of an author
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    string getAddress();

    // The get name function
    // Purpose: get the name of an author
    // Parameters: none
    // Returns: none
    string getName();
};
```

I'm not sure how to output the book info inside of the displayBooks() function.

Comment: Where *exactly* do you fail? What have you tried?

Comment: You must have recently talked about the `<<` operator in class.

Comment: in the displayBooks function in diver.cpp is where I need to write the code to display all of the book data but I don't know what to write to output it. I've tried Book::Book(books[i]); but I don't know what else to do

Comment: molbdnilo, yes. I obviously need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `getAuthor()` member function in your `Book` class.

```
Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
```

In `displayBooks()` iterate through the `myBooks` vector.

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {
    Book temp1 = myBooks.at(i);
    Author temp2 = temp1.getAuthor();
    cout <<"Author Name "<<temp2.getName()<<" Address "<<temp2.getAddress();
    cout <<"Book Title "<<temp1.getTitle();
    /**
     * print the remaining attribute.
     */
}
```

Comment: Ok I did that but when I compile I get the error _main already defined in driver.obj            and the other error one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: Oh wait I fixed that. Thank you soooo much!!

Comment: Glad to help @riahtron3000